# How to turn a relative path script (js) import to an absolue one with a url for XSS ? (more details below)

Tags: xss, javascript, client-side

I have a parameter whose value is injected in the HTML as the following

```
<script src="/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/INJECT_HERE"> </script>
```

I was able to traverse back to just `/` but when I enter my xss hunter payload (let say its `https://bla.bla/xss.js`) the page actually requests
`https://targeet-company.com/https://bla.bla/xss.js`

So, it's requesting my url as a relative file on the server instead of fetching javascript from another website. Is this something the developers do to prevent XSS? or is it because I traversed backward so it's expecting a file?

How to turn this relative js import into an absolute one?

Also, I managed to inject double quotes but can't add any event handlers so, I am here

```
<script src="/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/" INJECT_HERE "> </script>
```

But without any event handlers, I can't do anything. Any help?

Comment: This is a pure programming question and is off topic on Security SE.

Comment: I mean i'm talking about this from a security prespective on how to exploit this behaviour, also about other web attacks, i see it fitting here.

Comment: when you say you "traversed backwards", what do you mean by that?  And did you get rid of the first "/"?

Comment: @pcalkins , by traverse backwards means i was able to return to web root by doing a variation of ../../../../, i basically don't know how to get rid of the first / , my question is basically is that possible, if so how?

Comment: it's still a relative path... doesn't matter that you went back to root...

Comment: @mentallurg imho it's a security question (you could rephrase it as "How to exploit injection into a relative path in a src attribute of a script tag?").

Comment: by "cant add any event handlers", do you mean the app filters them out? So as soon as you inject `" onX=y`, it becomes `"`? Or that you can't find an event handler that executes?

Comment: @tim yes the app filters them out, they seem to be doing that pretty well in fact.

Comment: how did you "traverse back"?